# Operating System Kernel file linking Error - unrecognised emulation mode: elf_i386

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

I am a software engineering undergraduate and I was given an assignment to duild an operating system. I have an apple M1 chip laptop . I installed UTM software for install ubuntu. I installed ubuntu correctly. After few steps i stuck when linking my kernel to loader file. I m attaching my source files.I am getting the error message like this.

ld: unrecognised emulation mode: elf_i386 Supported emulations: aarch64linux aarch64elf aarch64elf32 aarch64elf32b aarch64elfb armelf armelfb aarch64linuxb aarch64linux32 aarch64linux32b armelfb_linux_eabi armelf_linux_eabi

my loader.s file

global loader                   ; the entry symbol for ELF

```
MAGIC_NUMBER equ 0x1BADB002     ; define the magic number constant
FLAGS        equ 0x0            ; multiboot flags
CHECKSUM     equ -MAGIC_NUMBER  ; calculate the checksum
                                ; (magic number + checksum + flags should equal 0)

section .text:                  ; start of the text (code) section
align 4                         ; the code must be 4 byte aligned
    dd MAGIC_NUMBER             ; write the magic number to the machine code,
    dd FLAGS                    ; the flags,
    dd CHECKSUM                 ; and the checksum

loader:                         ; the loader label (defined as entry point in linker script)
    mov eax, 0xCAFEBABE         ; place the number 0xCAFEBABE in the register eax
.loop:
    jmp .loop                   ; loop forever
```

my link.ld file

ENTRY(loader)                /* the name of the entry label */

SECTIONS {
. = 0x00100000;          /* the code should be loaded at 1 MB */

```
.text ALIGN (0x1000) :   /* align at 4 KB */
{
    *(.text)             /* all text sections from all files */
}

.rodata ALIGN (0x1000) : /* align at 4 KB */
{
    *(.rodata*)          /* all read-only data sections from all files */
}

.data ALIGN (0x1000) :   /* align at 4 KB */
{
    *(.data)             /* all data sections from all files */
}

.bss ALIGN (0x1000) :    /* align at 4 KB */
{
    *(COMMON)            /* all COMMON sections from all files */
    *(.bss)              /* all bss sections from all files */
}
```

}

x-special/nautilus-clipboard
copy
file:///home/cha/Downloads/stage2_eltorito

My terminal code is
ld -T link.ld -melf_i386 loader.o -o kernel.elf

any help is really appreciated

Comment: Why are you attempting to select an x86 arch on ARM machine? If you want to cross-compile, you should install a cross-compiling toolchain.

Comment: can you instruct me to install a cross-compile toolchain

Comment: much appreciated your concern on this